# Embed XML in HTML (for Mozilla Nightly)

Tags: html, xml, firefox, mozilla

I've seen that there is another post with a similar name, but it doesn't help me.

I use this:

```
<embed src="../xml/menu.xml" />
```

to embed some XML content in a div from an HTML file. It is working (the content is displayed) in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not in Mozilla Nightly.

Do you know how to make it work even for Nightly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<object>` instead.  Per spec, `<embed>` will only show content handled via plug-ins and SVG, not random document types like XML.